# Most efficient way to reset own index in for loop at certain values

Tags: java, optimization, refactoring

I need to do this:

```
int boundary1 = 10;
int boundary2 = 30;
int boundary3 = 70;
int myIndex = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // do something with myIndex;
    myIndex++;
    // [reset myIndex to 0 at each boundary]
}
```

What I did before was, loop the `i` to each boundary, manually reset `myIndex`, and then manually restart the next loop from boundary to boundary. That's pretty ineffective. How would you do it?

**EDIT** OK, seems some didn't understand:
Within a for loop, I need to have another index that'll reset at certain points (called them boundaries here).

Comment: What? I can't be the only one who doesn't understand what's the question

Comment: Probably a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: edited for clarification. if you understand now, please stop the downvote. thanks.

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis Thanks, I didn't even know that site exists?!? Will post there next time... just posted here because 1 million similar questions and answers on SO had helped me so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for, your question is quite ambiguous and doesn't make much sense. From what I can gather, this what you want:

```
int boundary1 = 10;
int boundary2 = 30;
int boundary3 = 70;
int myIndex = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //do something with myIndex.
    myIndex++;

    if (i == boundary1 || i == boundary2 || i == boundary3)
    {
        myIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it isn't and update your post to give a better description, then I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: yes, that's it, aaarrgh... had my wires crossed on that, 'cause I was comparing `myIndex` to the boundaries instead of `i` ... thanks :)